# Address a generated button for clickevent

Tags: c#

I have a class that creates panels with controls based on my database. It creates a panel with a button on each panel, per row in DB. How do I address one specific button to make a click event?

I'm a rookie, and maybe abit over my head, but you don't learn to swim in shallow water ;)
Any help appreciated!

```
while (myDataReader.Read())
{
  i++;
  Oppdrag p1 = new Oppdrag();
  p1.Location = new Point (0, (i++) * 65);
  oppdragPanel.Controls.Add(p1);
  p1.makePanel();
}

class Oppdrag : Panel
{
  Button infoBtn = new Button();

  public void makePanel()
  {
    this.BackColor = Color.White;
    this.Height = 60;
    this.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
    this.Location = new Point(0, (iTeller) * 45);

    infoBtn.Location = new Point(860, 27);
    infoBtn.Name = "infoBtn";
    infoBtn.Size = new Size(139, 23);
    infoBtn.TabIndex = 18;
    infoBtn.Text = "Edit";
    infoBtn.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a method that matches the event thrown by clicking on the button.

i.e.)

```
void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // Do whatever on the event
}
```

Then you'll need to assign the click event to the method.

```
p1.infoBtn.Click += new System.EventHandler(Button_Click);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the event handler for the button when you create the button. You can even add a unique `CommandArgument` per button so you can distinguish one button from another.

```
public void makePanel()
{
  /* ... */
  infoBtn.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
  infoBtn.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonClick);
  infoBtn.CommandArgument = "xxxxxxx"; // optional
}

public void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Button button = (Button)sender;
  string argument = button.CommandArgument; // optional
}
```